# laravel validate unique fields on update

Tags: laravel, validation, field

I am using the L5 repository and it has the validator package (https://github.com/andersao/laravel-validator) but I am have problems to do the validation of the unique fields on update it, anyone to help me???

******the example bellow I tried in this way on RULE_UPDATE but no success..

**((((((FIELDS I WANT TO VALIDATE : people_id, email BECAUSE THESE ARE UNIQUE ONLY FOR REST OF THE USERS, NOT TO THIS CURRENT USER THAT ITS UPDATING )))))))**

calling the validation in the UserService.php:

use Prettus\Validator\Contracts\ValidatorInterface;

```
        public __construct(){
           $this->validator = \App::make('App\Validators\UserValidator');
        }
        save($data){

        if(!empty($data['id'])){

            $this->validator->with($data)->passesOrFail(ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE);

        }else{
            $this->validator->with($data)->passesOrFail(ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE);
        }
        }
```

namespace App\Validators;

use \Prettus\Validator\Contracts\ValidatorInterface;
use \Prettus\Validator\LaravelValidator;

class UserValidator extends LaravelValidator
{

```
protected $rules = [
    ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [

        'people_id' => 'required|unique:users',
        'active' => 'required',
        'available_chat' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'masters_id' => 'required',
    ],
    ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [

        'id' => 'required',
        'people_id' => 'required|unique:users,id,:id',
        'active' => 'required',
        'available_chat' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,id,:id',
        //'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        //'masters_id' => 'required',
    ],
];
protected $messages = [

        'id.required' => 'Usuário não encontrado!',
        'people_id.required' => 'Pessoa é obrigatório',
        'people_id.unique' => 'Pessoa já cadastrada',
        'active.required' => 'Obrigatório',
        'available_chat.required' => 'Obrigatório',
        'email.required' => 'Digite o e-mail',
        'password.required' => 'Digite a senha',
        'password.min' => 'Digite uma senha com 6 caracteres',
        'password.confirmed' => 'Confirme a senha corretamente',
        'email.unique' => 'E-mail já cadastrado',
];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the id of the register in method setId

```
$this->validator->with($data)->setId($id)->passesOrFail(ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE);
```

Comment: before you posted it I found the solution in this same way, thanks man!!!!

Comment: and now how to reference the id in the validation rules?

Answer (score 2):

> While updating you need to force a unique rule to Ignore Given ID

```
'people_id' => 'required|user,people_id,'.$id 
 //id is the primary id of the field which you want to update 
  with unique validation which must be ignored
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

Comment: in this way is success with the use of the Request class normaly, but with this package it do not work, I tried with the page error 'Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Constant expression contains invalid operations'

Comment: can u show me how you have triggered the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below changes it will work.
Add below code in your Validator for check Unique Email validation

```
    ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
                'email'  => 'required|unique:customers,email,id'
            ],
```

After that set id for validation code like this

```
    $this->validator->with($request->all())->setId($id)->passesOrFail(ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE);
```